# At Trump's inauguration, who was the man in the wheelchair and why is he important?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, inauguration

[image: Obama speaking to the his wife]

[image]

I'm trying to figure out who is this guy in the wheelchair and why is he so "important". Both (now former president) Obama and Mr. President Donald Trump shook hands with him and had a little chat. Was he a significant figure in politics in the 80's or so?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is [Bob Dole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Dole), the Republican Senate Leader from 1981 to 1996.

[image: Image 1]

*(image from Wikipedia)*

He was Gerald Ford's running mate and the Vice-Presidential candidate in the 1976 election.

In 1996, he ran for President against Bill Clinton, who was seeking for a second term in office, but wasn't successful.

---

Credits to **@user4012** for pointing out Dole's 1996 presidential campaign.